# CakePHP: Display user_name in BelongsTo where only user_id is stored

Tags: php, cakephp, belongs-to

I assume this is a common question so my apologies in advanced if this is at all annoying.

I have a few table relationships setup and would like to show the user_name rather than user_id when pulling up a related table which contains BelongsTo entries.

Is there a simple way to do a query for these names in their own tables for this set of relationships?

In particular, while displaying a list of PROJECTS, I am also displaying a list of related STATUSES. STATUSES have a BelongsTo relationship with both USERS and PROJECTS and I'd like to display the user_name and project_name rather than _id.

I am currently setting the PROJECT's controller to being recursive:

```
$this->Project->recursive = 2;
```

So it allows me to make calls to the STATUSES' related to the PROJECTS:

```
<?php echo $status['user_id'];?>
```

However, this is where I'd prefer to display user_name.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Can we see some code where you're actually calling the model's `find()` method?

Comment: And your models (Project, Status, User) too, please.

Answer (score 1):

In User model:

> var $displayField = 'user_name';

That would affect find('list') and scaffolding.

To display user_name in your second example, simply change it to:

> ```
> <?php echo $status['user_name'];?>
> ```